# Can a pitcher also be a designated hitter?

Tags: baseball

Suppose an American League Team ended up with a good-hitting pitcher e.g Yovani Gallardo, or from an earlier era, Ken Brett, who had established this reputation in the National League.

Could such a pitcher be a "designated hitter" (dh) for himself? If yes, could he continue to "dh" after being relieved as a pitcher?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the DH could go in to pitch and continue to hit. After he came off the mound, the pitchers would have to hit for themselves. Correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO.

[Rule 6.10(b)](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2013/official_baseball_rules.pdf)

> 2 It is not mandatory that a club designate a hitter for the pitcher, but failure to
>   do so prior to the game precludes the use of a Designated Hitter for that club
>   for that game.
>
> 10 Once the game pitcher bats for the Designated Hitter, such move shall terminate the Designated Hitter role for that club for the remainder of the game.
>   The game pitcher may pinch-hit only for the Designated Hitter.
>
> 12 Once a Designated Hitter assumes a position on defense, such move shall terminate the Designated Hitter role for that club for the remainder of the game

These rules combine to indicate quite clearly that the Pitcher cannot be named the designated hitter for himself. Specifically 12 would be the clearest case, the DH cannot appear on defense, which is the primary role of the pitcher.

What a team *could* do if they had a pitcher with sufficient value as a DH though is the have him DH and then allow him to pitch, perhaps in a closer type role. Though rule 15 indicate that he would not be allowed to warm up in the bullpen:

> 15 The Designated Hitter may not sit in the bullpen unless serving as a catcher in
>   the bullpen

Comment: Earl Weaver, long time manager of the Orioles had a lot to do with the creation of this rule. After the DH was instituted, Weaver would set a pitcher as the DH and simply pinch hit for him when the DH would come up, usually substituting based on match ups.

Comment: @Jerrod interested in a source on that, do you happen to have one?

Comment: The technique is actually called the phantom DH. http://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/designated_hitter

Comment: So what happens once a Designated Hitter assumes a position on defense, [and] such move shall terminate the Designated Hitter role for that club for the remainder of the game?" Does the team then bat with eight hitters, or does something else happen?

Comment: No, the pitcher bats in the substituted player's batting position.

Comment: @waxeagle: Then you could get a pitcher (e.g. Yovani Gallardo) to bat that way through the "back door." But the downside is that any reliever would also have to bat for himself.

Comment: @TomAu the DH is *always* optional, you just can't get it back if you either sub out your DH or don't start with one. That said in MLB, 99% of pitchers are worse hitters than 99% of hitters, so there is rarely a circumstance where you'd want your pitcher hitting if you can avoid it.

Comment: Then if I am understanding correctly, the DH could go in to pitch and continue to hit in the same spot in the lineup. But when he came off the mound, the new pitcher would have to hit for himself. Correct?

Comment: I love @Jerrod 's  comment I was looking for that.  It illustrates what a crappy convoluted rule this is, I hope somehow they can get rid of it.

Comment: @MarkMonforti it's *far, far* more likely to expand than disappear. It's a good bet the National League gets the DH in the next 5 years.

Comment: Man that would be awful.  I think I would get rid of my season tickets

Comment: @MarkMonforti Come have a chat! http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse