# MLB closer with walk off hit

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

I'm wondering if any closers have had a game winning hit or home run?
Since this requires the closer (pitcher) to be at bat, it implies that the game was hosted by an NL team.

Comment: [This](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/can-a-pitcher-also-be-a-designated-hitter) is an interesting aside on that.  Theoretically a good hitting pitcher could take over the DH role (or the pitcher could replace the DH if he were injured?).

Comment: Of course your scenario is probably indeed going to be very rare, almost certainly in an extra innings or large comeback situation, where a team has heavily depleted its bench of at least one of batters or pitchers (or the rare situation of a solid batting relief pitcher), such that the team does not pinch hit for the pitcher in such a key situation.

Comment: One thing to note: when you say closer... do you indeed intend to imply someone in a save situation?  Because that would further make it difficult, requiring a blown save first, then their own runs in response, and still most likely in extra innings due to the non-substitution!  Plus the fact that teams quite often make their pitcher changes in pinch hit situations themselves (or double switch) to prevent the pitcher from coming to bat for a while.

Comment: In the beginning I was thinking of any pitcher who enters the game for a save. Or in the rare case of a very meaningful game to stop the other team from scoring. But that sounds to be very hard to search for. For the sake of the question let's consider the last pitcher of a team their closer of the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there actually has been a pitcher to hit a walk-off homerun. This took place on April 25, 1986. Craig Lefferts (a left-handed pitcher and batter) hit a walk off homerun in the 12th inning while he was on the San Diego Padres.

Jim Hardin also hit a walk off home run as a pitcher on May 10, 1969. At the time he was playing for the Orioles and he hit it off of the Royals

http://m.mlb.com/news/article/174353432/craig-lefferts-marks-30-years-since-walk-off/